# Diodes and resistors theory

Tags: resistors, diodes, parallel, theory, circuit-theory

I came across a problem which I cannot calculate by theory.

How does this circuit with diodes and resistors work?

[image: diode in series with resistor]

In the above diahram, I can calculate the current simply by subtracting the voltage drop of the diode from the source voltage which gives 11.4V (the green value in picture.)  11.4 divided by 2k (the total of the resistors) gives 5.7 mA that is drawn and we can work out the voltage drop over each resistor.

The next circuit confuses me.

[image: diode in series with resistor in parallel with resistor]

Can someone please explain how we get the current through every component and the voltage drops? The other thing a normal voltage divider of 1k and 1k, 2k in total on a 12V supply will draw 6mA but in the diode circuit R3 only draws 4.2 mA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [diode and resistor in parallel with resistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/226646/diode-and-resistor-in-parallel-with-resistor)

Comment: No not really but wil do research about the shocky equation. Thanks.

Comment: Turn that circuit upside down then rethink what you said. Else use Millman's theorem.

Comment: Apparently, this problem wants you to ignore Shockley, and to assume that D1 always drops 0.6 V.

Comment: Use [Kirchhoff's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), and algebra.

Comment: Assuming it's an ideal diode, Try to perform two experiments, first short the diode, then evaluate the current, if the current in the right direction then the diode can be ignored. Else perform the second one, disconnect the diode and evaluate the voltage drop on the diode, if its positive on the diode, ignore it. Else its the first option

Comment: Shockley's equation uses the forward bias voltage applied on the diode. I read somewhere that shockley equation is an iteration. How do you iterate the equation if you dont now the forward bias voltage?

Comment: What I am actually asking is if i give you all a circuit diagram with random resistor values and we will use the 0.6 volt drop on the diode wich is standard for most general purpose diodes lets say, can you guys work out every current draw on each component and the voltages at certain point without any simulation software? How do you do that?

Comment: Can someone at least answer an example of this calculation. I like the idea of kirchhoff's law and shockley. I just want to see the calculation.

Comment: @Gideon "*How do you iterate the equation if you dont now the forward bias voltage?*" As mentioned in the linked answer (first comment), start with a *plausible* value. If the initial guess was *close* to the correct value, the iterations are likely to converge.

Comment: If you are familiar with KCL, can you [edit] the question to add the node voltage equations ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a simulation? Even if you have to calculate things the long-handed notepad way with pen or pencil, why wouldn't you also use a simulation to get a better answer?

Comment: The reason why I don't want to use a simulation is because I don't understand why this is happening. I would like to know why it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage drop over R1+D1 and R3 is the same: V<sub>1</sub> + 0.6 = V<sub>3</sub>
The currents through R1 and R3 add up in R2: I<sub>1</sub> + I<sub>3</sub> = I<sub>2</sub>
The total voltage drop is 12 V: V<sub>3</sub> + V<sub>2</sub> = 12
And Ohm's law: 1 kΩ × I<sub>1</sub> = V<sub>1</sub>, 1 kΩ × I<sub>2</sub> = V<sub>2</sub>, 1 kΩ × I<sub>3</sub> = V<sub>3</sub>

These six equtions are enough to [compute the results](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=i_1%2Bi_3%3Di_2%2C+v_1%2B0.6%3Dv_3%2C+v_3%2Bv_2%3D12%2C+1000i_1%3Dv_1%2C+1000i_2%3Dv_2%2C+1000i_3%3Dv_3),

Comment: Using Kirchhoff's law is so much simpler and makes sense. Thank you